# REST API validation for query string

Tags: api, rest

I'm designing a REST API using Laravel 5.1.

I'm curious is it necessary to validate query string?

```
https://www.example.com/users?page=1;count=20
```

what if user put page="abc" or count="abc"?. Should i return an error or just return empty result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory an URI is an atomic identifier, so you should return a `404 Not Found`, regardless of the wrong syntax or semantics. In practice, it's better to return a `400 Bad Request` and a detailed explanation of the error.